# I am facing issue while setting the top of nested scrollview at half of total height during loading of activity

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I want that when my activity will load, the top of scrollview will be at half of the screen height (like [img_1.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aTUg0A_aixH5RLh3sblGiA4LCuB4yzqM/view?usp=sharing)). But I am getting it at the bottom (like [img_2.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J1FevesmXGxTGcXBR4NKynJcQv2srMxp/view?usp=sharing)). And it must be scrollable (like [img_3.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WTYEVPQ2Oj6ervxG8Aydia1z73sb-l7r/view?usp=sharing), [img_4.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AbSTAC2StG3askOEHxrOOU_IwLB8-UsA/view?usp=sharing), [img_5.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hDryeYNJOzA4WyrlANBbxe1qw3NvOD35/view?usp=sharing) in drive link) up and down during scrolling.

And here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Main4Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="6dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/col_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:scrollIndicators="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_below_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="About me"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="650dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hDELP83a3YV1p1GxnfG0IpLmfwQFKWfr

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with me.

I just want the **AppBarLayout** height as MATCH_PARENT.
But when I open the activity for the first time, I need it's bottom to the half of the screen. And after that on scrolling, the **AppBarLayout** will expand like **IMAGE 3, 4, 5** uploaded by @Abhinav.

Answer (score 0):

You have define

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
   app:elevation="6dp">
```

Instead of that give some static value so you will get your result

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
   app:elevation="6dp">
```

Comment: I have tried it. but then i will not get image at full screen . When i will completely scroll down.